# How to create a new tab or window from a buffer?

Tags: buffers, tabbed-user-interface, command-line-window

I have several open buffers and want to open a buffer in `:ls` in a new tab or window.

I have found a way to do accomplish this, either by first executing `tabnew` or `C-w v` and then selecting the buffer using `:b<N>`.

Can the same be accomplished using a single command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new window from a buffer: `:sb<N>`(horizontally) or `:vert sb<N>`(vertically).

Create a new tab from a buffer: `:tab sb<N>`
        or create a new window and then press `<C-W>T`.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I wanted!

Answer (score 5):

While editing command line a "special" `#n` (see `:h cmdline-special`) is replaced with the n-th buffer name. Hence, all of the following work in Vim (`:h 42`):

```
:edit #42
:split #42
:tabedit #42
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank you, very useful!